# Swift Decode unique keys in JSON or ignore certain keys

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm practicing my Swift skills, this time I'm trying to make a Covid-19 tracker, and for this I found this [API](https://github.com/M-Media-Group/Covid-19-API), the thing is, that the format retrieved by `/cases` is something like this (changing keys to make it more readable)

```
{
    "Country1": {
        "All": {
            "property1": 0,
            "property2": "foo"
        }
    }, {
        "All": {
            "property1": "0",
            "property2": "bar",
        },
        "State1": {
            "property1": 0,
            "property3": "foobar"
        }
    }
}
```

And I made the following structs to decode it:

**Country**

```
struct Country: Codable {
    let All: [String: All]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case All
    }
}
```

**All**

```
struct All: Codable {
    let confirmed: Int?
    let recovered: Int?
    let deaths: Int?
    let country: String?
    let population: Int?
    let squareKmArea: Int?
    let lifeExpectancy: String?
    var elevationInMeters: String?
    let continent: String?
    let location: String?
    let iso: String?
    let capitalCity: String?
    let lat: String?
    let long: String?
    let updated: String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case confirmed
        case recovered
        case deaths
        case country
        case population
        case squareKmArea = "sq_km_area"
        case lifeExpectancy = "life_expectancy"
        case elevationInMeters = "elevation_in_meters"
        case continent
        case location
        case iso
        case capitalCity = "capital_city"
        case lat
        case long
        case updated
    }
    
    init(confirmed: Int?, recovered: Int?, deaths: Int?, country: String?, population: Int?,
         squareKmArea: Int?, lifeExpectancy: String?, elevationInMeters: String?,
         continent: String?, location: String?, iso: String?, capitalCity: String?,
         lat: String?, long: String?, updated: String?) {
        self.confirmed = confirmed
        self.recovered = recovered
        self.deaths = deaths
        self.country = country
        self.population = population
        self.squareKmArea = squareKmArea
        self.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy
        self.elevationInMeters = elevationInMeters
        self.continent = continent
        self.location = location
        self.iso = iso
        self.capitalCity = capitalCity
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.updated = updated
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        self.confirmed = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .confirmed)
        self.recovered = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .recovered)
        self.deaths = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .deaths)
        self.country = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .country)
        self.population = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .population)
        self.squareKmArea = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .squareKmArea)
        self.lifeExpectancy = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lifeExpectancy)
        self.elevationInMeters = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .elevationInMeters)
        self.continent = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .continent)
        self.location = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .location)
        self.iso = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .iso)
        self.capitalCity = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .capitalCity)
        self.lat = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lat)
        self.long = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .long)
        self.updated = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .updated)
        
        do {
            self.elevationInMeters = try String(container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .elevationInMeters) ?? 0)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            print("Not a number")
            self.elevationInMeters = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .elevationInMeters) ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

The elevation in meters can come in either String or Int value (4+ digits long > String (appends a comma), otherwise Int) (Idea taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936022/2180785)

And I try to decode it this way

```
if let decodedData = self.jsonUtilities.decode(json: safeData, as: [String : Country].self) {
    print(decodedData)
}
```

My above `decode` method looks like this:

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(json: Data, as clazz: T.Type) -> T? {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let data = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: json)
        
        return data
    } catch {
        print(error)
        print("An error occurred while parsing JSON")
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50094049/2180785) where they suggest adding all the Coding Keys there, but these are a ton.

I haven't added all the keys, as it's an 8k+ lines JSON, so I was wondering if there's an easier way to decode it, as I can't think of a better way to decode this JSON with unique keys.

Alternatively if I could ignore all the keys that aren't `"All"` might also work, as I'm just trying to get the totals per country and their locations to place them in a map.

So far I get this error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Diamond Princess", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "All", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "recovered", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
An error occurred while parsing JSON
```

And afaik it's because it's not finding the key "Diamond Princess" which is a state (or so I believe) in Canada (according to my JSON), because I haven't added it for the reasons above.

Comment: "Diamond Princess" is not a state in Canada :) Canada has provinces, but it's also not that. "Diamond Princess" is a cruise ship where one of the first covid outbreaks happened.

Comment: @NewDev welp, I guess I just made two whoopsies in this question so far, but that also means I learnt two things for culture knowledge. Thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have dynamic keys, you could decode it as `[String: ...]` dictionary.

The structure of the JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "Canada": {
     "All": { ... },
     "Ontario": { ... },
    ...
  },
  "Mexico": { ... },
   ...
}
```

All the country stats have the key `"All"` and if that's all you need then you could create the following structs:

```
struct Country: Decodable {
    var all: CountryAll
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case all = "All"
    }
}

struct CountryAll: Decodable {
    var confirmed: Int
    var recovered: Int
    //.. etc
}
```

and decode as:

```
let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Country].self, from: json)
```

Comment: So, this is a way to "ignore" certain keys, very interesting, give me some mins and I'll give it a try

Comment: `Codable` only takes the keys you define as a property of the type you're decoding

Comment: Wow! This really helped me a lot, I was taking long approaches for solving this and it was quite simple in the end. Thanks! I learnt 3 things from you today :)